# table. vertical-align. on columns with stickyfooter, and header

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I am using http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ for a fluid header/footer/content page.

I am trying to do a two column layout for my site. Left div navigation; the right div content.
The left column has content vertically aligned in the center. The content is both vertically-aligned in the center as well as horizontally aligned in the center.

I'm stuck at laying out the navigation.

I would think I should be able to make a div for the nav container {float:left; width:300px;display:table;} then make the nav_content div something like {height:300px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}.

I thought at first the issue was that the container needs to span 100% height of whatever was left over after the footer and then the content would be able to vertically align the height. (The only thing I can find is 'background-hacks' to achieve this and Jscript to calculate and dynamically update absolute height. It doesn't seem right to me that those are the only options.) But when I set the parent div to a set height, then try and vertically-align the content, it still does not work. I really do not understand as all the resources I have read states that the parent contains table display and table-cell can use the vertical-align middle. (does using float mess this up?)

Here is a crudely drawn layout I am trying to accomplish.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kggEG.png

Here is the idea with the code.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="side">
            <div id="nav">
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>



#side
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #B5E3FF;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    display:table;
}

#nav
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 350px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for anyone who tries to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<style>
#footer {
    background-color: #999;
}
#header {
    background-color: #0C6;
}
#side
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #B5E3FF;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    display:table;
    height: 350px;
}

#nav
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 350px;
    width:30%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="header">This is header</div>
    <div id="nav">This is Nav</div>
    <div id="side">This is side</div>   
    <div id="footer">This is footer</div>
</div>
</body>
```